# awk add numbers in row

Tags: awk

I'm trying to wrap my head around the AWK command.
From what I've read I can see that it it treats the data in a text file as columns 
but I need to add up all values in a specific row not column.

e.g. I wanted to add all the values to the right of Scorpion to get the value of **150**

```
awk   'BEGIN {FS=","} {NR=2 ;  calc1=$2+$3+£4+$5; print calc1 }' timetable.txt
```

```
timetable.txt

Sub zero,    40,  40,  40, 20

Scorpion,    20,  40   60, 30

Raiden,      15,  10,  10, 15
```

Comment: Note the `£4` in the middle of your command. Also note the capital `P` in `Print`. Might be a couple of issues there for you to clean up... Also, assigning a value to `NR` makes no sense, see the awk man page for what `NR` means. Finally - with any shell you can't use single quotes inside a single-quote-delimited script.

Comment: As is the missing field separator behind the 40 in column 3 of "Scorpion" ...

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=","} $1=="Scorpion"{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){sum+=$i}} END{print "Sum="sum+0}' Input_file
```

Comment: Thanks ill give that a try.   Just looking to understand it as well.   Where do we specify the row ?  Scorpion being on the 2nd row.   And how in psuedo code.

Comment: @Confuseis, code is looking for string `Scorpion` not for specific line here, if any line has that string it will collect the sum, kindly do let me know in case of any queries here?